# Specify Chef run list

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

Where can I find documentation about how to write:

```
chef-solo --override-runlist "role["somerole"],recipe[mycookbook::recipe]"
```

Saw in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18566301/1197775).

I mean what are the possible values for `role`, `recipe`? where are they defined?

Can I list possible values using CLI?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please clarify. Are you asking which roles are available with this type of chef-solo invocation? Or you're asking what are roles and recipes? Or... ?

Answer (score 2):

The values are determined by your infrastructure. You have to write the roles and recipes, or download them from the community site. There is an infinite list...

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is rude.